# Create dynamic table & column reference without INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using following dynamic table reference several times in my workbook which is causing performance issues:

```
SUMIFS(INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$B$4,2,0)&"[kpi_name]"),INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$2:$B$4,2,0)&"[filter1]"),UPPER($H13))
```

based on the input in A1 I need to switch between table1, table2 and table3.

I do this by building a vlookup map in A2:B4 that return the appropiate table names and using this + column name in a indirect formula.

I would like to move to a better solution using INDEX or another named range.
I tried to use a named range with a formula returning the right table reference:

```
=IF(A1=1,table1,IF(A1=2,table2,IF(A1=3,table3,0)))
```

But this way I can't use named_range[column of table]

Also I can't get a working solution with INDEX...

Comment: You can't, you are stuck with this model.  If it was a row or column reference then we could use INDEX but since it is the parent table, parent sheet is the same, INDIRECT is the only way to go.

Comment: You could fill a fourth table with vba in a worksheet_change event based on the choice in A1, then refer to that table in all your formula.  That should speed things up.

Comment: would you add a screenshot

Comment: FWIW, I'd use CHOOSE rather than nested IF statements, but you'll still need to specify the column name, or use INDEX/MATCH to find the column using the name.

Comment: Since you're using Tables and structured references, you can use the suggestion made by @Rory like this `=SUMIFS(CHOOSE(A1,Table1[kpi_name],Table2[kpi_name],Tabe3[kpi_name]),CHOOSE(A1,Table1[filter1],Table2[filter1],Table3[filter1]),UPPER($H13))`.

Comment: thanks @Domenic!
Can I create the column reference also variable? Table2[A1] or Table2[TEXT(A1)] didnt work...

Comment: solved it, will add it as an answer. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of the initial question I came up with follow:

```
SUMIFS(INDEX(CHOOSE(A1,TABLE1,TABLE2),,MATCH(VAR_COLUMN_NAME,INDEX(CHOOSE(A1,TABLE1,TABLE2),1,0),0)),INDEX(CHOOSE(A1,TABLE1,TABLE2),,MATCH("filter1",INDEX(CHOOSE(A1,TABLE1,TABLE2),1,0),0)),UPPER(ABC))
```